# Can the independence of random variables hold for their functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent continuous random variables on $\mathbb{R}$. Define: $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ as a $C^\infty$ map on $\mathbb{R}$.

Then is it possible to find the necessary and sufficient condition(s) such that:

$X$ and $f(Y)$ are still two independent random variables?

Comment: How should $X$ and $f(Y)$ become dependant?

Comment: you just need $f$ to be a measurable function with respect to the sigma field of $Y$.

Comment: @Math-fun Which is what you need to make $f(Y)$ a random variable in the first place ...

Answer (score 2):

Independence of $X,Z$ random variables occurs when we verify the following relation:

$$ P(X \in A, Z \in B)= P(X \in A) P(Z \in B)$$

In our case $Z = f(Y)$ we check

$$P(X \in A, f(Y) \in B)= P(X \in A, Y \in f^{-1}(B)) = P(X \in A) P(Y \in f^{-1}(B)) = P(X \in A) P(f(Y) \in B) = P(X \in A) P(Z \in B) $$

Hence independence follows.

Comment: $P(x\in A,Z\in B)=P(X\in A)P(z\in B)$ is a necessary but insufficient condition for independence if I am not wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is the definition of independence of independent random variables once this holds for $A,B$ are arbitrary (measurable) sets